# Code not execute in all pc for assign email address from excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a tool to automate require data emailed to the concern users.
Data is in one sheet and reference of Location and email address is in second sheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim EmailApp As Object
Set EmailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Object for Outlook
Dim NewEmailItem As Object

For r = 2 To Worksheets("Receipant").Cells(Worksheets("Receipant").Rows.Count, Range("C2").Column).End(xlUp).Row
           FltrCrit1 = Sheets("Receipant").Cells(r, 3)
           Workbooks.Add
           ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FltrCrit1 & ".xlsx"
           Set wbNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FltrCrit1 & ".xlsx")
           ThisWorkbook.Activate
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Select
           ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$p$" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FltrCrit1
           ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$p$" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select
           Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
           Selection.Copy
           wbNewWorkbook.Activate
           wbNewWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
           wbNewWorkbook.Save
           wbNewWorkbook.Close
           
         Set NewEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(0) 'Object for mail within Outlook
         NewEmailItem.To = Sheets("Receipant").Cells(r, 1)
```

But in few Systems following error generated  at the line number 20. i.e.  `NewEmailItem.To = Sheets("Receipant").Cells(r, 1)`

> Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)':
> Automation error
> The server threw an exception.

And when I remove the sheets reference and input the literal text of email address it will execute without any error. E.g. `NewEmailItem.To = “abcd@xyz.com”`

I could not getting why few users facing error of the same tool even os and office version are same.

Comment: Did you try to debug it step by step with F8 in those computers where it fails?

Comment: Yes I tried with debugging every step it given an error on the above said line.  So I store  cell value into new string variable e.g. EmailTo= Sheets("Receipant").Cells(r, 1) and NewEmailItem.To = EmailTo this solve my problem. But still I have question why above code didn't work on few systems?